# boost::optional<size_t>& = boost::none compilatin error

Tags: c++, boost

If I have an optional argument for a method as

```
boost::optional<size_t>& currentPos = boost::none;
```

I get this compilation error

```
error: default argument for 'boost::optional<unsigned int>& currentPos' has type 'int boost::detail::none_helper::* const'
```

Can't I use `boost::none` to `boost::optional<size_t>&` ?

Comment: Make it `boost::optional<size_t> currentPos = boost::none;`

Answer (score 2):

`boost::none` isn't a global, universal `boost::optional<T>` value (indeed, what would `T` be?). Rather, it is a helper tag value that allows the *construction* of actual `boost::optional<T>` instances. So all you can do is create a new, temporary value from it, but temporary values cannot bind to non-const references.

Either change your reference to a constant one, or your design.

Answer (score 1):

While `make_optional(T x);` knows that it needs to create `optional<T>` from the type of its argument, `none` doesn't have an argument. It would have type `for all T, optional<T>`, if type system in C++ had real polymorphism. But there's no parametric polymorphism in C++, so `none` is a value of phantom type [`none_t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/none_t.hpp), that could be cast into any of `optional<T>`. Be careful passing it around.

Regarding your question, look at the [definition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/none.hpp) of `none`.

```
none_t const none = (static_cast<none_t>(0)) ;
```

Isn't it obvious, that you cannot

- make a non-const reference (which implies changing value of the variable it references to) to a constant variable?
- make a reference of type `optional<T>` to a variable of type `none_t`, which is not a subtype of `optional<T>`?